# XML Schema Validation: Identity Constraint Key?

Tags: xml, xsd

I've been trying to build a pepXML to mzIdentML converter and using [this validator](http://www-bs2.informatik.uni-tuebingen.de/services/OpenMS/analysisXML/index.php)

to make sure my implementation is correct. Currently, I keep getting this error:

```
"Validation error in file './files/test-test.mzid' line 24231 column 13:
identity constraint key for element 'mzIdentML' not found"
```

I can't figure out what this error even means. I've asked the people who wrote the validator but I never got a reply.

If this error is specific to the validator and/or schema, then I guess I'll just delete this question, but if this is a general error that can occur when validating XML schema, then can someone please explain to me what this error means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identity constraints are used to enforce uniqueness of an attribute — kind of like it's an `xml:id` attribute. (See the [XML Schema spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cIdentity-constraint_Definitions).)

It sounds like there is an element which is saying it has an identity constraint, but is giving a reference to an identity constraint key which doesn't actually exist. Can't really say more without looking at the schema/doc :)